# ¿Cómo puedo autoincrementar ID de Sqlite en PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, \
    QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QMessageBox, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QLabel, QGridLayout, QSlider, QDialog


class Aplicacion(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Aplicacion, self).__init__()

        # ---------------- CARACTERÍSTICAS TABLA ----------------
        self.tabla = QTableWidget(0, 5)
        self.tabla.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ['ID', 'NOMBRE', 'APELLIDO', 'EDAD', 'SEMESTRE'])

        # -------------------- ETIQUETAS --------------------
        self.etiqueta_id = QLabel("ID:")
        self.etiqueta_nombre = QLabel("Nombre:")
        self.etiqueta_apellido = QLabel("Apellidos:")
        self.etiqueta_edad = QLabel("Edad:")
        self.etiqueta_semestre = QLabel("Semestre:")

        # ------------------ CAJAS DE TEXTO ------------------
        self.texto_id = QLineEdit()
        self.texto_nombre = QLineEdit()
        self.texto_apellido = QLineEdit()
        self.texto_semestre = QLineEdit()
        self.texto_edad = QLineEdit()
        self.deslizador = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)

        # ------------------ RESTRICCIONES ------------------
        self.texto_id.setMaxLength(2)
        self.texto_id.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())
        self.texto_nombre.setMaxLength(35)
        self.texto_apellido.setMaxLength(90)
        self.texto_semestre.setMaxLength(2)
        self.texto_semestre.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())
        self.texto_edad.setMaxLength(2)
        self.texto_edad.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator())

        # ------------------ SLIDER --------------------
        self.deslizador.setMinimum(15)
        self.deslizador.setMaximum(25)
        self.deslizador.setValue(15)
        self.deslizador.setTickInterval(1)
        self.deslizador.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
        # ------------------ PLACEHOLDER --------------------

        self.texto_id.setPlaceholderText("Identificador del alumno")
        self.texto_nombre.setPlaceholderText("Nombre del alumno (a)")
        self.texto_apellido.setPlaceholderText("Apellidos del alumno (a)")
        self.texto_edad.setPlaceholderText("Edad del alumno (a)")
        self.texto_semestre.setPlaceholderText("Semestre")
        # ---------------------- BOTONES ----------------------
        boton_agregar_datos = QPushButton('Agregar')
        boton_agregar_datos.clicked.connect(self.validar_formulario)

        boton_eliminar_datos = QPushButton('Eliminar')
        boton_eliminar_datos.clicked.connect(self.eliminar_datos)

        boton_editar_datos = QPushButton('Editar')
        boton_editar_datos.clicked.connect(self.editar_datos)

        boton_limpiar_cajas = QPushButton('Limpiar')
        boton_limpiar_cajas.clicked.connect(self.limpiar_cajas)

        self.deslizador.valueChanged.connect(self.desliza_edad)

        # -------------- UBICACIÓN EN CUADRÍCULAS --------------
        celda = QGridLayout()

        # ETIQUETAS.
        celda.addWidget(self.etiqueta_id, 0, 0)
        celda.addWidget(self.etiqueta_nombre, 1, 0)
        celda.addWidget(self.etiqueta_apellido, 2, 0)
        celda.addWidget(self.etiqueta_edad, 3, 0)
        celda.addWidget(self.etiqueta_semestre, 5, 0)

        # TEXTO.
        celda.addWidget(self.texto_id, 0, 1)
        celda.addWidget(self.texto_nombre, 1, 1)
        celda.addWidget(self.texto_apellido, 2, 1)
        celda.addWidget(self.texto_edad, 3, 1)
        celda.addWidget(self.deslizador, 4, 1)
        celda.addWidget(self.texto_semestre, 5, 1)

        # BOTONES.
        celda.addWidget(boton_agregar_datos, 0, 2)
        celda.addWidget(boton_eliminar_datos, 1, 2)
        celda.addWidget(boton_editar_datos, 2, 2)
        celda.addWidget(boton_limpiar_cajas, 3, 2)

        # ---------------ALINEACIONES VERTICALES ---------------
        caja_vertical = QVBoxLayout()

        caja_vertical.addLayout(celda)
        caja_vertical.addWidget(self.tabla)

        # ---------------- VENTANA PRINCIPAL -------------------
        self.setWindowTitle("Registros de alumnos")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("db.ico"))
        self.tabla.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        self.resize(560, 550)
        self.setLayout(caja_vertical)

    def validar_nombre(self):
        nombre = self.texto_nombre.text()
        if nombre == "":
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def actualizar_nombre(self, id_editar):
        n_nombre = self.texto_nombre.text()

        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_("UPDATE alumnos SET nombre = '{}' WHERE alumno_id = '{}'".format(
            n_nombre, id_editar))

    def actualizar_apellido(self, id_editar):
        n_apellido = self.texto_apellido.text()

        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_("UPDATE alumnos SET apellido = '{}' WHERE alumno_id = '{}'".format(
            n_apellido, id_editar))

    def actualizar_edad(self, id_editar):
        n_edad = int(self.texto_edad.text())

        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_(
            "UPDATE alumnos SET edad = {} WHERE alumno_id = '{}'".format(n_edad, id_editar))

    def actualizar_semestre(self, id_editar):
        n_semestre = int(self.texto_semestre.text())

        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_("UPDATE alumnos SET semestre = {} WHERE alumno_id = '{}'".format(
            n_semestre, id_editar))

    def validar_editado(self):
        if self.tabla.selectedItems():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def editar_datos(self):
        if self.validar_editado():
            alumno_id_editar = self.tabla.selectedItems()[0]
            self.id_editar = alumno_id_editar.text()

            try:
                if self.validar_nombre():
                    self.actualizar_nombre(self.id_editar)
                else:
                    pass
            except:
                pass

            try:
                if self.validar_apellido():
                    self.actualizar_apellido(self.id_editar)
                else:
                    pass
            except:
                pass

            try:
                self.actualizar_edad(self.id_editar)
            except:
                pass

            try:
                self.actualizar_semestre(self.id_editar)
            except:
                pass

            finally:
                self.subir_datos()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error",
                                "No has seleccionado a nadie", QMessageBox.Ok)

    def subir_datos(self):
        indice = 0
        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_("SELECT * FROM alumnos")

        while consulta.next():
            alumno_id = consulta.value(0)
            nombre = consulta.value(1)
            apellido = consulta.value(2)
            edad = consulta.value(3)
            semestre = consulta.value(4)

            self.tabla.setRowCount(indice + 1)
            self.tabla.setItem(indice, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(alumno_id)))
            self.tabla.setItem(indice, 1, QTableWidgetItem(nombre))
            self.tabla.setItem(indice, 2, QTableWidgetItem(apellido))
            self.tabla.setItem(indice, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(edad)))
            self.tabla.setItem(indice, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(semestre)))

            indice = indice + 1

    def validar_formulario(self):
        if self.validar_nombre():
            alumno_id = int(self.texto_id.text())
            nombre = self.texto_nombre.text()
            apellido = self.texto_apellido.text()
            edad = int(self.texto_edad.text())
            semestre = int(self.texto_semestre.text())

> QUIERO QUE EL ID SE AUTOINCREMENTE SIN QUE TENGA QUE INGRESAR EL NÚMERO EN EL CAMPO.

            consulta = QSqlQuery()
            consulta.exec_("INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')".format(
                alumno_id, nombre, apellido, edad, semestre))

            self.subir_datos()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Formulario incorrecto",
                                "No has agregado a nadie", QMessageBox.Ok)

    def validar_eliminacion(self):
        if self.tabla.selectedItems():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def eliminar_datos(self):
        if self.validar_eliminacion():
            seleccion = self.tabla.currentIndex()
            alumno_id = self.tabla.selectedItems()[0]

            consulta = QSqlQuery()
            consulta.exec_(
                "DELETE FROM alumnos WHERE alumno_id = " + alumno_id.text())

            self.tabla.removeRow(seleccion.row())
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error",
                                "No has seleccionado a nadie", QMessageBox.Ok)

    def conexion_base_de_datos(self):
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('alumnos_database_new.db')

        if db.open():
            return True
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(
                None, "Ha ocurrido un error al querer conectarse.", QMessageBox.Cancel)
            return False

    def crear_tabla(self):
        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        consulta.exec_(
            "CREATE TABLE alumnos(alumno_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            "nombre TEXT, apellido TEXT, edad INTEGER, semestre INTEGER)")

    def desliza_edad(self):
        valor_edad = str(self.deslizador.value())
        self.texto_edad.setText(valor_edad)

    def limpiar_cajas(self):
        self.deslizador.setValue(15)
        self.texto_id.clear()
        self.texto_nombre.clear()
        self.texto_apellido.clear()
        self.texto_edad.clear()
        self.texto_semestre.clear()

    def iniciar(self):
        if not os.path.exists('alumnos_database_new.db'):
            self.conexion_base_de_datos()
            self.crear_tabla()
        else:
            self.conexion_base_de_datos()
            self.subir_datos()

db_alumnos = QApplication(sys.argv)
aplicacion = Aplicacion()
aplicacion.iniciar()
aplicacion.show()
sys.exit(db_alumnos.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The AUTOINCREMENT Keyword
https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

```
def crear_tabla(self):
    consulta = QSqlQuery()
    consulta.exec_(
        #"CREATE TABLE alumnos(alumno_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        "CREATE TABLE alumnos(alumno_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        "nombre TEXT, apellido TEXT, edad INTEGER, semestre INTEGER)")

...

def validar_formulario(self):
    if self.validar_nombre():
        #alumno_id = int(self.texto_id.text())      # ---
        nombre    = self.texto_nombre.text()
        apellido  = self.texto_apellido.text()
        edad      = int(self.texto_edad.text())
        semestre  = int(self.texto_semestre.text())

#> QUIERO QUE EL ID SE AUTOINCREMENTE SIN QUE TENGA QUE INGRESAR EL NÚMERO EN EL CAMPO.
        consulta = QSqlQuery()
        #consulta.exec_("INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')".format(
        #    alumno_id, nombre, apellido, edad, semestre))
        consulta.exec_("""
            INSERT INTO alumnos (`nombre`,`apellido`,`edad`,`semestre`) 
            VALUES('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')""".format(nombre, apellido, edad, semestre))    
        self.subir_datos()
    else:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Formulario incorrecto",
                            "No has agregado a nadie", QMessageBox.Ok)
```